# How to synchronize sustain strings with the rest of the orchestra

Tags: composition

I am trying to write a track that has sustain strings and when I listen to it, it seems to me that the strings are delayed with respect to the rest of the orchestra. Strings have a slower attack and they sound as if they are not synchronized with other instruments, can you suggest a way to fix this?
I know I must play them earlier so they can catch up with the other instruments, but how much earlier should they play to synchronize with a pluck sounding instrument like celesta?

Comment: You mean other than 'play early'?

Comment: How much earliear should I play them given a specific value of attack so the strings can synchronize with a pluck type instrument?

Comment: Until it sounds right.

Comment: This will require a lot of trial and error is there a faster way?

Comment: Just play it in live.

Comment: Another thing I would like to know is if I am using whole notes and have a volume swell that increases from silence, peaks at the middle of the note an decreases towards the end of the note, if I play the strings earlier, would that mean that I change the volume swell to follow the notes?

Comment: Or change your strings sound to have a faster attack.

Comment: If I do that (change to faster attack) and use volume swell curves, will it sound the same as playing it earlier with slower attack?

Comment: You may be trying to use a “string pad” voice/patch... “pads” have slow attacks. You would be better off using an instrumental patch like violin, viola, etc.

Comment: @paradox if you are using software with a piano roll, select all and drag it earlier a little bit.  It will hardly take long at all.

Answer (score 2):

Learning to program strings is like learning to play an instrument.

If it feels like they're playing late, then you have to play them early. The way to do this is literally to play them early. A bunch of samples won't all have the same attack so you will just have to play it until your hands get the idea your brain wants to hear.

If you want to use some kind of expression with that, then the best way to 'feel' it is to map something like mod wheel to the expression controller, so you can play it all in in one go.

If you click it all in from an editor & try to adjust later, it will always sound stiff.

One trick is to never play chords with strings - record each line separately, each with its own controller set.

Answer (score 0):

"how much earlier should they play...?"

Sufficiently.   And that's the only possible answer! Experiment.

But also investigate your available string sounds.   There are 'pad' strings, programmed with a slow attack.  But I expect you also have some with more attack.  Try using them instead.  Try using both at once - one for rhthtmic attack, one for sustain.